# Как ускорить код (Python 3.7)?

Tags: python, олимпиада, runtime

> Серийные номера автомобилей “Жорже” являются идущими подряд элементами
>   числовой последовательности N. Десятичная запись i-го элемента этой
>   последовательности строится конкатенацией всех целых положительных
>   чисел, начиная с 1 (номер первого автомобиля) и заканчивая i.
>   Например, N[2]=12, N[11]=1234567891011. При этом, если серийный номер
>   автомобиля делится на 2^S, то его владельцу дарят бесплатную гарантию
>   на 3 года. Вам задано количество экземпляров N и число S. Вычислите,
>   сколько человек получит гарантию.
>   **ВНИМАНИЕ! 1 <= S <= 10^18!**

Столкнулся с проблемой превышения лимита времени на одной из задач. Превышение лимита всего на 0.089s. Ниже приведен код. Как можно "бустануть его" еще больше, не изменяя сути? Если кто-то знает C++ - перепишите код на него (я учил плюсы год назад).
Код (правка 16.05 23:19 - этот код осталось доработать совсем чуть-чуть, он близок к истине):

```
def go(args):
    N = int(args.split()[0])
    S = int(args.split()[1])
    counter = 0
    S = (1 << S) - 1
    cur = 0
    mul = 10
    minn = min(100001, N + 1)
    for i in range(1, minn):
        if i == mul:
            mul *= 10
        cur = (cur * mul + i) & S
        if not cur:
            counter += 1
    if N > 100000:
        counter *= (N // 100000)
    cur = 0
    mul = 10
    if N > 100000:
        for i in range(0, (N % 100000) + 1):
            if i == mul:
                mul *= 10
            cur = (cur * mul + i) & S
            if not cur:
                counter += 1
    return counter


print(go(input()))
```

З.З.Ы. Самый быстрый код на данный момент:

```
def go(args):
    N = int(args.split()[0])
    S = int(args.split()[1])
    counter = 0
    S = (1<<S)-1
    cur = 0
    mul=10
    for i in range(1, N + 1):
        if i == mul :
            mul *= 10
        cur = (cur*mul + i) & S
        if not cur:
            counter += 1
    return counter
```

Comment: Написал код на плюсах, но т.к. учил давно, то есть несколько ошибок:

Comment: А можно на словах, что этот код вообще должен делать?

Comment: У нас есть serie - размер серии автомобилей. Номер i-той машины - строка вида 12345...(i-1)i. Нужно найти кол-во машин, чьи номера делятся на 2 ** number.

Comment: Номера машин это числа? Номера машин могут начинаться с нуля? Если к примеру serie=6, то `000001` будет считаться корректным номером?

Comment: Нет. Смотри: номер 1-й машины: 1, номер второй: 12, номер 13-ой: 12345678910111213.

Comment: Я конечно не на что не намекаю, но когда говорят при степени двойки, начинает вонять битовыми масками...

Comment: Номера машин имеют непостоянный размер? Крайне странная задача...

Comment: Даже если я переведу все в биты, это не ускорит код.

Comment: Да. Номера машин имеют непостоянный размер. Т.к. для i-той степени двойки необходимо, чтобы число из последних i цифр делилось на 2**i, я решил не хранить строку-монстр, а сделать очередь.

Comment: Есть переменная serie - кол-во автомобилей в серии. Есть number. Как образуются номера - вы написали. И в ответе должно быть число автомобилей, чьи номера делятся на 2 в степени number. Я правильно понял?

Comment: Опишите точное условие задачи в теле вопроса с примером данных и результатом

Comment: Серийные номера автомобилей “Жорже” являются идущими подряд элементами числовой последовательности N. Десятичная запись i-го элемента этой последовательности строится конкатенацией всех целых положительных чисел, начиная с 1 (номер первого автомобиля) и заканчивая i. Например, N[2]=12, N[11]=1234567891011.
При этом, если серийный номер автомобиля делится на 2**S, то его владельцу дарят бесплатную гарантию на 3 года.
Вам задано количество экземпляров N и число S. Вычислите, сколько человек получит гарантию.

Comment: in: 1 1, out: 0; in: 10 1, out: 5; in: 10 2, out: 2; in: 10 3, out: 1; in: 10 4, out: 1; in: 10 5, out: 1; in: 10 6, out: 1.

Comment: > Есть переменная serie - кол-во автомобилей в серии. Есть number. Как образуются номера - вы написали. И в ответе должно быть число автомобилей, чьи номера делятся на 2 в степени number. Я правильно понял? || Да, именно так.

Comment: внесу свои 5 копеек. append медленная штука.лучше сразу создать list=[None]*10000 и пихать по индексу

Answer (score 2):

```
def go(args):
    N = int(args.split()[0])
    S = int(args.split()[1])
    counter = 0
    S = (1<<S)-1
    cur = 0
    mul=10
    for i in range(1, N + 1):
        if i == mul :
            mul *= 10
        cur = (cur*mul + i) & S
        if not cur:
            counter += 1
    return counter
```

Comment: Забыл сказать, 1 <= N <= 100000; 1 <= S <= 6. На (100000; 6) выполняется дольше минуты.

Comment: примерные времена исполнения - этот код, код MBo и ваш 0:00:00.047501 0:00:00.100001 0:00:01.080017

Comment: Я протестил. Ваш код выполняет 12 тест за 280ms, код MBo: за ~500ms, но почему-то 13 тест выполняет с один. скоростью.

Comment: Я понял! N <= 10^18, значит нужно менять код. Ваш код действительно самый быстрый на данный момент.

Comment: Я просто умножил counter на N // 100000 и сделал поиск от 1 до n % 100000. Это потребует максимум в 2 раза больше времени.

Answer (score 2):

Без строк, `100000 6` менее секунды, однако и твой вариант работает не более пары секунд

```
def go(args):
    serie = int(args.split()[0])
    number = int(args.split()[1])
    counter = 0
    queue = []
    getter = [2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64][number - 1]
    val = 0
    mul = 10
    for i in range(1, serie + 1):
        if i in (10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000):
            mul *= 10
        val = (val * mul + i) % 1000000
        if val % getter == 0:
            counter += 1
    return counter

 >>100000 6
 >>1562
```

Comment: Идея понятна, падает на 13 тесте (опять на 0.089s больше лимита!). Буду думать, но ты красавчик.

Comment: Тогда, наверное, подход надо менять. Можно копейки ловить на битовой маске вместо % и поиск in заменить чем-то, но перебор всех значений есть перебор. Поскольку S мало, для каждого S можно табличку маленькую предрасчитать для нескольких ключевых значений. Или закономерность понять - где и какие отклонения от `N//2^s` происходят